# CanJS future element event binding

Tags: javascript, canjs, canjs-control

The [CanJS documentation](http://canjs.com/docs/can.Control.html#section_Listeningtoevents) has an example like this:

```
var Todos = can.Control.extend({
    init: function( element , options ) { ... },

    'li click': function( li ) { ... },
    'li .destroy {destroyEvent}': function( el, ev ) { 
        // previous destroy code here
    }
});
// create Todos with this.options.destroyEvent
new Todos( '#todos', { destroyEvent: 'mouseenter' } );
```

However, if `#todos` is created after `new Todos` is called, no event is bound the future element, or if a method within `Todos` removes a pre-created `#todos` dummy as deemed necessary. How can I rebind custom events within a Control? After a `Control` instantiation call?

Answer (score 1):

Just use Control.on();
http://canjs.com/docs/can.Control.prototype.on.html

You can specifiy which event to be listen to or just call the function without parameters like this the control listen to all events.

Comment: The controller is binded to the element you send as a parameter, why would you instantiate a controller if the element you are going to bind it doesn't exist yet?